# Clicking anywhere on the page causes nav with class affix-top to change to class affix

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a web page I need to style for a client.  I cannot change the header they created.  My navbar is a div with id="nav" class="affix-top" and is fine until I click anywhere on the page.  When I click anywhere the class in my navbar changes to "affix", if I click again it change to "affix-top" and displays again.

see below

```
//I've added some styles to keep navbar from disappearing when scrolling:
    #nav.affix-top {
        position: relative;
        top: 0px;
    }    
    #nav.affix {
        position: fixed;
        top: 101px;
    }

//It works ok.
//But when I click on the page, or a button or anything the navbar disappears
//behind the header due to the class changing.  I tried this, but it did not
//work.

$(document.body).click( function() {
    $('#nav').removeClass('affix');
    $('#nav').addClass('affix-top');
});
```

I expect my navbar to remain unchanged when clicking on the page.
Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like your code is doing exactly what you coded it to do?

Comment: No, it is not.  It no longer disappears behind header when scrolling, but when clicking anywhere on the page causes it to disappear behind the header - my javascript didn't work.  I am hoping someone that knows javascript well could assist in how to make the class not change to "affix" when a user clicks on anything on the page.

Comment: There are plenty of people here that know javascript well, but we also need to understand the issue. Seems nobody understands your question since you have not gotten an answer. I'd recommend providing [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I would if I could, but I don't know how to repro the issue as I don't understand why it's happening.  Some background js plugin I suspect is changing the class on the nav div when you click or scroll on the page. My css works for scrolling except it's not very cleanly done; if I scroll just 1 pixel it does the same thing as if you clicked on the page.  I tried this to find the nav but it also does not work:
```
    var element = document.getElementById("#nav");
    if (element.classList.contains('affix-top')) {
        console.log('affix-top');
    }

```

Comment: I had the same symptoms - this fixed it for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19711202/bootstrap-3-affix-plugin-click-bug